# Python Regular Expression replace between div

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to replace all text between the div class="one" tag
What I have so far works, but only if everything is on one line.
text_msg is the

```
text = re.sub('<div class="one">.*?</div>',new_text,text_msg,re.DOTALL)

<div class="one">replace this 
more text here
another line
</div>
```

I have tried re.MULTILINE, got nowhere.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use the [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag.

Comment: @eugenhu Did you read the question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Woops, apparently not sorry.

Comment: The fourth argument is count, [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.sub). You need to specify flags as a keyword argument.

Comment: And do something like `re.sub('(<div class="one">).*?(</div>)',r"\1" + new_text + r"\2",  text_msg, flags=re.DOTALL)` so the div tags don't get cut off from the final string.

Comment: So adding () around my div's will keep my div's and replace only the text between.

Comment: @user3525290 Not quite, you put the div tags around brackets to say you want to capture these matches so that you can use backreferences (`\1`, `\2`) to refer back to them again in the replacement string, you can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace) around 3 examples down. The other answers have suggested using [lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertions which are equally valid and could be cleaner solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went and modified your `re.sub`.  The problem with your current code is that you aren't using the `flags` key word arguments to specify flags.  I also changed your regex to look for a precursor pattern `(?<=<div class="one">)` and post pattern `(?=<\/div>)`.

```
import re

text_msg = """
<html>
<head>
<title>Terrible webpage</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="one">Cool text!</div>
<b>test</b>
<div class="one">Second text!</div>
<div class="one">third text!</div>
<div class="one">replace this 
more text here
another line
</div>

</body>
</html>
"""

print(re.sub('(?<=<div class="one">).*?(?=<\/div>)',"out",text_msg,flags=re.DOTALL))
```

Output:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Terrible webpage</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="one">out</div>
<b>test</b>
<div class="one">out</div>
<div class="one">out</div>
<div class="one">out</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `.` with `[\s\S]` in your regex as shown below:

`<div class=\"one\">[\s\S]*?<\/div>`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/L8gwWB/1)

**Explanation:**

- `<div class=\"one\">` - literally matches `<div class="one">`
- `[\s\S]*?` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character(include the newline character), as few as possible
- `<\/div>` - literally matches `</div>`

Comment: Thanks for the advice.